# Time Dummies and Time Trend in the same equation

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data

Can we run this regression:

$Y_{it} = a + bX_{it} + c_2Time_2 + ... + c_TTime_T + ht + U_{it}$

$i = 1,2,..., N;$ $t = 1,2,3...,T$

Where
​

- $Time_T$ are time dummies
- $t$ is the time trend.

In other words, can we run a regression with both time dummies and and a time trend? I suspect that we cannot, but am looking for a more formal explanation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The way you have written the model some parameter will be unidentified hence the answer is: NO.

To see this consider the model without covariates  $x_{it}$ without loss of generality

$$(1) \ \ y_{it} = a + \sum_{t=2}^T c_t T_t + h \cdot t + \epsilon_{it}$$

for $t=1,...,T$.

For $t=1$ the term $th = h$ which we can add to the constant $a$ to get $b:=(a+h)$ hence the model can be rewritten

$$ y_{it} = b + \sum_{t=2}^T c_t T_t + h \cdot (t-1) + \epsilon_{it}$$

such that the time trend $h \cdot (t-1)$ is now $0$ for time period 1 for which the model includes no dummy. For the other periods the value of the time trend $h \cdot (t-1)$ is simply added to the dummy coefficient $c_t$ to get $\tilde c_t := c_t + h \cdot (t-1)$ allowing us to rewrite model

$$y_{it} = b + \sum_{t=2}^T \tilde c_t T_t  + \epsilon_{it}.$$

Because the model with time trend has been shown equivalent to a model without the timetrend the timetrend itself is not identified.

You can easily simulate this in R to see what happens in a model where you simulate (1) and then tries to estimate it

```
set.seed(1)   
library(data.table)
T <- 5
N <- 1000
a <- 1
c <- c(0,abs(rnorm(T-1)))
h <- 2

id <- sort(rep(1:N,T))
time <- rep(1:T,N)

dt <- data.table(id=id,time=time)
setkey(dt,id,time)

dt[,y:=a+c[time]+h*time,by=id]

# pooled panel data regression
lm(y~as.factor(time)+time,data=dt)
a + h
c[2:T] + h*(2:T-1)
```

resulting in the output

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ as.factor(time) + time, data = dt)

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)  as.factor(time)2  as.factor(time)3  as.factor(time)4  
           3.000             2.626             4.184             6.836  
as.factor(time)5              time  
           9.595                NA  

> a + h
[1] 3
> c[2:T] + h*(2:T-1)
[1] 2.626454 4.183643 6.835629 9.595281
```

where the coeffient on time is not estimated and the constant term is $a+h$ and the time dummy coefficients are given by the formula $c(t) + h(t-1)$.

(note: I have simulated the model without error $\epsilon_{it}$ but the result are the same with error terms)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and probably should. The trick is to properly identify a minimally sufficient model that may include events, level shifts, seasonal pulses AND ARIMA structure.

Comment: Hi: When you put $h \times t$ in the model, you're assuming that there's a time trend in addition to the effect of the regressors $X_{i}$. I  would google for "trend stationary versus difference stationary" and possibly test that assumption of trend stationarity. This response doesn't cover the issue of the time dummies which is a different discussion altogether

Comment: I think that you may be missing the subtlety that trends don't always..start at the beginning there may be multiple trends which can be found via Intervention Detection schemes.........

Comment: Possibly but I don't think that means that you automatically include a trend term ? does it ?

Comment: Only if significant ..

Comment: Prepare a new question that has two  two  time trends an i will respond. report your  data

Comment: right but the order of the various tests one does matters. that's why I think it's best to forget about time dummies at the start and first figure out the issue of trend stationary, difference stationary or just plain stationary ? – mlofton yesterday

Comment: the tests for one versus the other are done simultaneously ... thus the "most probable solution "  via F tests is selected .. .. potentially leading to a mix'n match .

Comment: yeah, my "style" is just to look at things one at a time rather than throwing everything in at once but that's just me. statistically, you're right that things should be tested simultaneously. good point.

Comment: AUTOBOX does look at things/options/improvements one at at a time and then identifies the best of these options and proceeds.